# Need to find an unused number in a nested object mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to create a Express webserver which does the following -
Register and Sign in
Once the user signs-in the user is redirected to a "Control panel", where they choose specifications for a docker container.

Mongoose schema

```
  email: String,
  password: String,
  docker: {
    site: String,
    adminpwd: String,
    hostPort: Number,
    cpus: Number,
    memory: Number,
    storage: Number
  }
})
```

The docker object is appended to the email and password fields after a post in the controlpanel page.

```
app.post('/control-setup/:userid',
//validation
[
  body('site').isURL({allow_underscores: true}),
  body('admin').isLength({ min: 6 })
], (req,res) => {
   const errors = validationResult(req);
     if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
       return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
}
const userid = req.params.userid
//Setup or Edit
var site = req.body.site
var adminpwd = req.body.admin
var cpus = req.body.cpus
var memory = req.body.memory
var storage = req.body.storage
//Needs a function to get the next available port
var hostPort = findhostPort()
//Cutting https:// from input
var site_name = site.slice(8)
//Save or Edit in DB
Users.updateOne({_id: userid}, {docker: {site: site, adminpwd: adminpwd, hostPort: hostPort, cpus: cpus, memory: memory, storage: storage}}, {upsert: true, new: true},
  function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log('Docker Parameters Setup in User' + result)
  res.redirect(userid)
})
})
```

The problem is in the `hostPort` variable, I'm trying to create a function that will go through mongoDb and find an available port.

I tried using for loops but it wouldn't work.
I'm clearly missing the correct logic here.

Would really appreciate some help as I'm a newbie to NodeJs and Development as a whole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [distinct](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-distinct) to find all the ports already used, and then generate a free port number.

```
const ALL_POSSIBLE_PORT_NUMBERS = [...]

function async findhostPort () {
  const usedPorts = await User.distinct('docker.hostPort')
  for (let port of ALL_POSSIBLE_PORT_NUMBERS) {
    if (userPorts.indexOf(port) == -1) {
      return port
    }
  }
}
```

Some caveats:

- You will need to make the `docker.hostPort` a unique field so the DB will throw an error when trying to save a duplicate hostPort, as simultaneous requests to this method will get the same port number.
- I'm assuming you have an array of all possible port numbers as some port ranges are restricted, and you will probably want to keep some for internal use
- Using `distinct` will get slower as you get more models. If it becomes a problem, you can consider caching the list of unused ports in memory and remove from it every time a new one is created.

Comment: This looks great!

Comment: Just a few questions -
Do you mean I will need to make docker.hostPort an _id field?
Right I aim to use the port range 8000-8005.
Currently not considering more models but will definitely keep it in mind

Comment: @FirdausAga No, you can add a unique index to any field in mongo. There is an example here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/schema.html#schema_Schema-indexes.
If you try saving a duplicate hostPort, it will raise an error which you can catch, and then you can replace the hostPort with a new untaken one